# Replace a specific value inside of a string

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building an Angular 9 app.
In this app I am creating search filters for the Shopify Graphql API.

I am building a query and the result is:

```
first: 1, query: "tag:'featured-1'", after: 'eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo32MjYzMTI0MDAwO3TQxLCJsY3XN0X3ZhbHVlIjo2MjYzMTI0MDAwOTQxfQ=='
```

The result is a string. I want to replace the value for after (inside the ' ') and if there is no new value for after: '' I want to remove it.

In other words, how can I replace the below value or if the next one is empty remove it from the string?

```
eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo32MjYzMTI0MDAwO3TQxLCJsY3XN0X3ZhbHVlIjo2MjYzMTI0MDAwOTQxfQ==
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you post the result looks like a JSON, can't you just set .after = '' ?

If not, this replace should do the job:

```
let emptyAfterPropRegex = /(, after:\'\')/;
let nonEmptyAfterPropRegex = /after:\'.+\'/;

if (emptyAfterPropRegex.test(result)){
  result.replace(emptyAfterPropRegex, '');
} else {
  result.replace(nonEmptyAfterPropRegex, 'after:\'Whatever you want past here\'')
}
```

note that for this, I assume the ' comes right after : inside the string, like such:

```
"after:'eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo32MjYzMTI0MDAwO3TQxLCJsY3XN0X3ZhbHVlIjo2MjYzMTI0MDAwOTQxfQ=='"
```

If not, either add a space in the regex or even remove brackets if necessary..

Comment: I tried it but it only works if the string ONLY contains the "after:" part and not if the string contains "first: 1, query: "tag:'featured-1'".@cedric S

Answer (score 0):

```js
function replace(str) {
  var newStr = str.replace(/,? *\bafter *: *''/, '')
  newStr = newStr.replace(/(\bafter *: *').+?'/, `$1'`)

  return newStr
}

console.log(replace('') === '')
console.log(replace(`after:''`) === '')
console.log(replace(`after: ''`) === '')
console.log(replace(`before: 1, after:''`) === 'before: 1')
console.log(replace(`after:'23'`) === `after:''`)
console.log(replace(`after: '23'`) === `after: ''`)
```